# Browserify - How do make variables accessible to my modules?

Tags: javascript, variables, module, browserify

I am wondering what is the correct way to make variables available to my various modules. I use a number of jQuery object selectors (e.g. `$('body')`, `$('#someId')` ect) in various  modules and i would rather not have to repeatedly declare theme in each module if i can avoid it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a module with all these common elements, and require that everywhere?

```
// pageElements.js
var $ = require('jquery');
module.exports = {
    body: $('body'),
    someElement: $('#someId')
}

// other files
var PageElements = require('./pageElements.js');

console.log(PageElements.body);
```

Comment: Hi Corina, i was just testing something similar only i declared a object literal 'var selectors = { $body: $('body') }' and then used 'module.exports = $selectors'. Is this the preferred method for providing app wide access to variables ? and is there any major difference in how approached it?

Comment: No, I don't think there's a major difference to how you have approached it. It's tricky to say if this is the "preferred method" to provide app wide access to variables, since it depends on your app. Generally, you wouldn't want to share *all* variables across all modules, since it's like having a global for your app, however, like I already said, this really depends on your app. It should probably be fine for now, since at least it will be easy to maintain - if you need to change a selector, you only need to change it in one place.

Comment: So far i only have 3 or 4 selectors i want to share. Thank you for your help.